# Can I use Visual Studio 2005 for programming with Exchange Server Managed API 1.1?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

My requirement is to develop a client application for retrieving calendar items from Exchange Server 2010. MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633626(v=EXCHG.80).aspx suggests the IDE Visual studio 2008 for programming with EWS managed API 1.1. I have to interface my application with other applications which were developed by VS2005 so can I use Visual studio 2005 for programming with EWS managed API 1.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Managed API requires .NET 2.0, which is used by Visual Studio 2005.